# How to initialize Apex Controller attached to Lightning Component before render?

Tags: apex, lightning

So I'm having trouble finding the correct pattern to solve this problem. I have a custom lightning component, with an apex controller assigned to it. There's an apex method, `controllerInit`, which I need to execute before the component renders. However, `controllerInit` is not static, so I can't call it from the component's js controller, which means I can't call it on init via `<aura:handler>`. On a VF page, I'd simply set the action attribute where I set the controller, but that doesn't seem to be an option in lightning components.

So how do I manage this? Is it possible to call a non-static apex method on the initialization of a lightning component?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't directly instantiate an Apex Code controller, because view state isn't a thing in Lightning. Anything you want to save between round trips needs to be passed back to the client.

Either pass the information back and forth between the client and server, or use static initializer blocks. Note that static initializers will run every time the server is called, so that may result in performance issues.